# jQuery .add() using generated element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through an array, using it's values to create a collection of elements to later be added to the DOM.

In doing so I'm using this code:

```
$().add($('<span />', {
    class: 'child',
    text: 'test'
})).appendTo('.container');
```

Or something similar... the generated element is not added to the collection. Here's a fiddle illustrating the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dygerati/WTYSQ/2/

Comment: `$().add` ? Why this construct ?

Comment: Heres a hint: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined

Comment: $('.container').append(your_new_element);

Comment: The format seems odd since it's a very simplified example of what I'm doing in my code. I'm really just wondering why the $.fn.add function doesn't work like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple array and push the new elements to your array.

```
var spans = new Array();
console.log(spans.length);

spans.push($('<span />', {
    class: 'child',
    text: 'test'
}));

console.log(spans.length);   
$('.container').append(spans);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WTYSQ/4/
In your posted fiddle you are also mixing the container and parent class, which is why `append()` doesn't work still. I named both container.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize append() took a native array. I'm still wondering why the jQuery add() function doesn't work as I expected, but I'll stop caring pretty quick.

Comment: Because `add()` doesn't change the original selection as you suppose. Take a closer look at the second code block: http://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 1):

No need to create an empty jQuery object. Also, there was no `.container` in your HTML. Use this code:

```
var spans=$('<span />', {
    class: 'child',
    text: 'test'
});  

$('.container').append(spans);
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WTYSQ/3/)

Comment: It's the add() method that I'm testing specifically, since in my actual code I'm going through a large for loop and adding elements that I generate. Then, after the loop completes, adding all to the DOM.